# VPS vs Raspberry Pi and Arduino

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino, vps

I want to implement this project...

[image: project description image]

In the image I have:

1. One and unique analog signal
2. One analog to digital converter
3. The output is carry out to several modules (executing FIR and rewriting the its output)
4. Collecting the new signal (ModuleID, PositionValue, ValueSignal)

   - I need to collect all information of modules (40 units) in one PC, **what Card or Port (one Multiplexing or 40 units) is recommended?**

PD: I'm worry about the performance (core, RAM) of VPS and the cost for it.

Comment: I've removed all but your last question here because the first two are borderline off-topic. It's also easier to answer your question as single questions, rather than lots of things at once.

Comment: Your other two questions would be better off in separate questions, though they may be off topic here. You might get better results on another site.

Comment: You've cross-posted this on 4 different sites: [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48768/755), [HardwareRec.SE](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/859), [RaspPI.SE](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37701), and [Arduino.SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/17238).  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.